# How is curcumin effective in fighting cancer?

Tags: cancer

Can you explain the mechanisms of how curcumin affects cancer cells and how effective it is?

More reading:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25667441
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1208/s12248-009-9128-x

Comment: Can you please add some references to this research?

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25667441

Comment: Since I cannot post more links with my reputation I will post them here  http://www.cancerletters.info/article/S0304-3835(07)00105-X/abstract  
http://europepmc.org/abstract/med/1578097  
http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.4161/cbt.7.9.6659  
http://europepmc.org/abstract/med/16521985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inflammation is a promoting factor in tumor progression.Curcumin has been proven to be a potent anti-inflammatory agent.
A warning:
There has been considerable amount of bogus research in "miracle natural" compounds, including curcumin. I vouch personally for the study (PMID: 19793800) where curcumin has been studied in inflammation/tumor progression mouse model.

Answer (score 0):

I did not check curcumin in depth, but I think its mechanism is similar to resveratrol's. Both activate SIRT1, which suppress tumors.

- [Activation of SIRT1 by curcumin blocks the neurotoxicity of amyloid-β25-35 in rat cortical neurons.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24755072)
- [SIRT1, Is It a Tumor Promoter or Tumor Suppressor?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2631220/)

Comment: I threw a reference in the OPs comments. May also inhibit SP-1, STAT3 and NF-kß pathways.